# Getting the child img inside a div using $(this); [on click event]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the child image of a clicked div.
I want to get it's src value. But it's returning undefined.
Could someone point me in the right direction?

Tried using Jquery .find() https://api.jquery.com/find/
Tried using Jquery .children() https://api.jquery.com/children/

Both return undefined.

```
for (let i = 0; i < $('#draw-raster > div').length; i++) {
    $(document).on('click', '#raster-item'+i, () => {
        let image = $(this).children('img').attr('src'); //undefined
        let image2 = $(this).find('img').attr('src'); //undefined


        if (image) {
            console.log(image);
            return alert("image child found!");
        }

        return setTimeout(() => {
            $('#raster-item'+i).children('img').hide();
        }, 4500);
    });
    $('#image'+i).hide();
}
```

load html:

```
   for(let i = 0; i < 16;  i++)
    {
        let image = displayImages();

        $('#draw-raster').prepend(
            "<div id=raster-item" + i + " class='imageh"+i+"' data-id=" + i + "><img src='"+ displayImages() +"' class='image "+i+"' id='image"+ i +"' alt='Failed to load image' width='173.19' height='107.3'></div>"
        );
    }
```

html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Memory</title>
    <script src="inc/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/css/boostrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/css/memory.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container justify-content-center">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-9">
              <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header bg-dark" style="color:white;">
                      <h2>Memory</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                      <section class="col-12 mx-auto" id="draw-raster">

                      </section>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3">
              <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header bg-dark" style="color:white;">
                      <h2>Turns</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                      <div id="turns">Turns: 0</div>
                      <div id="sets">Sets: 0</div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-success col-12" type="button" id="reset">Reset scores</button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="inc/js/memory.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Both attempts return undefined, i'm uncertain what would work.
Yes, I've been spamming google too. :'^)

Comment: show the html code. and why on click inside a loop?

Comment: I'll post the html, i'm currently just experimenting as i'm quite new to javascript. So code might seem a bit strange.

Comment: have you tried to debug the value of `$(this)` before using .childrend() or .find()? print out that value in the console.

Comment: it seems you are trying to bind events to multiple elements with ids. Its best  to go with class instead,

Comment: May be you could try with [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: #draw-raster and #raster-item do not exist in your HTML

Comment: These are generated by jquery @Gerard

Comment: @BasKruithof $('#draw-raster > div').length returns zero. Maybe part of the code is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of notes on your code:

1) If you want to use `this` you'll need to switch from an arrow function back to a regular anonymous function. Arrow functions don't have a `this` of their own and will borrow the context from their outer lexical environment. It's why your code keeps return undefined.

2) You don't need a loop. The benefit of using jQuery is that you can operate on collections of elements all at once. In your case you're attaching a single event listener to a parent element (here: `document`) and waiting for events to bubble up from the `.raster-item img`s and be "captured". This is called [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and is useful when you want to process new elements added to the DOM after it has loaded.

2) You will find it easier to use a class instead of many ids.

Here's an example based on your code with these changes:

```js
// Use event delegation to add an event listener to the element with
// the container class that watches out for click events on **all**
// elements with the raster-item class that contain images
$('.container').on('click', '.raster-item img', function () {

  // `$(this)` will be the image element, so simply grab its src
  // from the attribute
  console.log($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="raster-item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/555/fff.png" /></div>
  <div class="raster-item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/777/fff.png" /></div>
  <div class="raster-item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/999/fff.png"/></div>
  <div class="raster-item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/bbb/fff.png" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for this. You can harness the power of **event bubbling** with vanilla JavaScript.

In the web page below, the code inside the `script` tags, listen for a click event and runs some code if that event happens, i.e. bubbles, through a DIV element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Clicked div img</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="catcher">
    <p>This is a div with an image inside</p>
    <img src="image-to-pick.jpg" alt="image to pick" ()>
  </div>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      if (event.target.tagName == 'DIV') {
        var imgToPick = event.target.querySelector('img');
        console.log(imgToPick.src); // add your code here
      } 
    }, false);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In other words, you trigger a "click event" whenever you click on that page, that event bubbles up until it reaches the root of the HTML document (which you can imagine as an upside-down tree where the root is the html tag). 
If you don't need or don't want to let it bubble to the elements "above" you DIV, you can also stop the propagation of that click event by using `event.stopPropagation()`, right after you handle the img src.

You can find more info about how this works [here on MDN (Mozilla Dev. Network)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure in what context you need to do this, but with jquery it's pretty straight forward.

If you have multiple images within a parent div, you can set the child images as the selecters for the click event, and return each image src when clicked on directly.

The resulting jquery is only three lines long this way, and you can add as many images as you like to the parent div:

```
<div class="image-container">
  <img id="first" src="first-source-goes-here.jpg" alt="img text" />
  <img id="second" src="second-source-goes-here.jpg" alt="img text" />
  <img id="third" src="third-source-goes-here.jpg" alt="img text" />
</div>


$(".image-container > img").click(function() {
  // replace 'alert' with what ever you need it to be
  alert( $(this).attr("src") )
})
```

EDIT:

In response to Andy's comment on my answer below, if you are loading images once the DOM has been loaded, then you could run a check on the click parent div to see if there are any images within it before returning the source:

```
$(".image-container").click(function() {
    if( $(this).children("img").length > 0 ) {
    alert( $(this).find("img").attr("src") )
  }  else {
    alert('there are no images here')
  }
})
```

Comment: Note that the OP is loading the images in after the DOM has loaded so you'll need to use event delegation.

Comment: @Andy Good point, I have edited my answer and inserted a check to see if there are any images in the parent div before returning the img src